# How to show a carto map in an ionic 2 app?

Tags: carto, carto-js

Has anyone shown a carto map in an ionic 2 app? When I used ionic 1 there was no problem, because it is angular js and I could add the library in the index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css">
  <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
```

and then use it in a `controller.js` like that:

```
var mapa;
      mapa = new L.Map('mapa', { 
        center: [39,-6],
        zoom: 9
      })
```

But the problem is that now I'm using ionic 2, so it's angular 2, typescript. After adding the libraries I try to do the same code above in the `.ts` file, but it can't find the name `L`.

Has anyone idea how to show my map? Or how to use a js library in typescript?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ionic platform, but I do use Angular 2 so forgive me if this is not applicable. The Carto.js library is on github, and you can install it as a node package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cartodb

Comment: Regarding the tagging, this looks more a ionic question than anything related with CARTO

Comment: I have asked this question in other pages, and finally I used the answer of this one:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76234/c%C3%B3mo-mostrar-un-mapa-de-carto-en-ionic-2-o-angular-2
That works for me. I tried to use the node package but it was easier for me not to change my code, so that's why I first chose that solution. Thanks!